# Passing the type of the property to generic function

Tags: c#, vb.net, system.reflection

I am reading a text file, translate the data where each line either goes in header object or items object. I am having an issue with nullables

'p' in below code is coming from

```vb
Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = GetType(UploadMain).GetProperties()
```

The code below throws the error:

> Invalid cast from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'

```vb
p.SetValue(header, Convert.ChangeType(dataObject, p.PropertyType))
```

the corresponding property in the class

```vb
private _orderDate As Date?
        Public Property OrderDate As Date?
            Get 
                Return _orderDate
            End Get
            Set(value As Date?)
                _orderDate = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

After looking around, found the following function, which i translated from C#

```vb
Public Class ChangeTypeUtlity

        Public Shared Function ChangeType(Of T)(ByVal value As Object) As T
            Dim conversionType As Type = GetType(T)

            If conversionType.IsGenericType AndAlso conversionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(GetType(Nullable)) Then

                If value Is Nothing Then
                    Return Nothing
                Else
                    Dim nullableConverter As NullableConverter = New NullableConverter(conversionType)
                    conversionType = nullableConverter.UnderlyingType
                End If
            End If

            Return CType(Convert.ChangeType(value, conversionType), T)
        End Function

    End Class
```

I have tried it with both type1 and type2 but getting error that it is not defined.

```vb
Dim type1 as Type = p.[GetType]()
Dim type2 As Type = p.PropertyType
p.SetValue(header, ChangeTypeUtlity.ChangeType(Of type2)(dataObject))
```

How can i pass my property type to the above function?

You can give the solution in C#. It doesn't need to be VB.Net

Comment: Your problem is with ChangeType, do you even need it? If you do, detect if the property is Nullable, if it is you can then use Convert.ChangeType(dataObject, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.PropertyType))

Comment: I have been asking the same question myself as well and looking into it. From learning point of view, still would like to know how to pass the property type.

Comment: @the_lotus please move your comment as an answer so that i can accept it. `Convert.ChangeType(dataObject, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.PropertyType)) ` helped solve the issue. I need to use nullable properties plus some other data that is weird as well like ints being passed as decimal. This is a vendor file, i have no control over it.

Comment: ChangeType is extraneous even for C#.  The line from the_lotus is basically identical to the code I use for the same purpose in a C# module.

Comment: @learning... I'm glad it helped. I don't know how to properly write an answer for this but I copy/pasted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with ChangeType, do you even need it? If you do, detect if the property is Nullable, if it is you can then use [GetUnderlyingType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Convert.ChangeType(dataObject, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.PropertyType))
```